# Ordering by a specific user in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

Below query gets results as listed in results 1 
I would like it to display as result set 2 IE the logged in user shows first

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
              CLIENT_BRANCH BRANCH,
       ACCOUNT_NO,
       CLIENT_SPECIALIST
  FROM CL$CLIENTS
 WHERE COMPANY_ID = :P0_COMPANY_ID
```

Results 1: (actual output)

```
Client_id   Branch                       Account_no CLIENT_SPECIALIST
1000001034  Training Force Isando        FTEC01       LAUREN
1000001035  Training Force Isando        EZUL01       Jack
1000001798  Training Force Isando        ISMEP02      SAMUEL
1000002064  Training Force Parktown      TTEL01       LAUREN
1000002191  Phalaborwa                   FOSK01       WICKUS
1000002314  Training Force Nelspruit     RUD01        ERICK
1000002318  Training Force Phalaborwa    SUS08        ZANELE
```

What I want is something like this:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
                  CLIENT_BRANCH BRANCH,
           ACCOUNT_NO,
           CLIENT_SPECIALIST
      FROM CL$CLIENTS
     WHERE COMPANY_ID = :P0_COMPANY_ID
     ORDER by :APP_USER (First)
```

Results 2 (Desired output)

```
Client_id   Branch                       Account_no CLIENT_SPECIALIST
1000001034  Training Force Isando        FTEC01       LAUREN
1000002064  Training Force Parktown      TTEL01       LAUREN
1000002191  Phalaborwa                   FOSK01       WICKUS
1000002314  Training Force Nelspruit     RUD01        ERICK
1000002318  Training Force Phalaborwa    SUS08        ZANELE
1000001035  Training Force Isando        EZUL01       Jack
1000001798  Training Force Isando        ISMEP02      SAMUEL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
                  CLIENT_BRANCH BRANCH,
           ACCOUNT_NO,
           CLIENT_SPECIALIST
      FROM CL$CLIENTS
     WHERE COMPANY_ID = :P0_COMPANY_ID
     ORDER BY DECODE(client_specialist, :APP_USER, 1, 2)
```

This says order by client specialist, when the value = :APP_USER then put that first, else 2nd.